# Coordinates are not submitted

Tags: android, geolocation, coordinates

So I'm trying to get the actual coordinates of the smartphone and then submit it. For this purpose I am working with a (non-optimal) email solution. I want to get the coordinates and then submitting them by email.

If I press the button, it should get the coordinates and then putting them into mail.

Somehow I only get 0.0 into the email client, which should be the default values.

Anyway, here is my relevant code:

I initialise lat and lon with double in the public class.

```
public LatLng getLocation()
{
    // Get the location manager
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    String bestProvider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(bestProvider);

   finden

    try {


        lat = location.getLatitude();
        lon = location.getLongitude();
        //überschreiben der Variabeln lon & lat funktioniert

        return new LatLng(lat, lon);
    }
    catch (NullPointerException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

And this is my button.

```
final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addbutton);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                getLocation();
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
                //i.setType("message/rfc822");
                i.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
                i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL  , new String[]{"adress@example.com"});
                i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject - New Location was added");
                i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT   , "Latitude: " + lat + "  Longitude: " + lon " );
                try {
                    startActivity(i);
                } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
                    Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "There are no email clients installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
        });
```

So what is my fault? The app is running, but it wont get the coordinates.

Comment: is `LatLng()` your method?

Answer (score 0):

Have you provided the ACESS_FINE_LOCATION in the manifest file? You need this permission to access location.

You need to add this in the manifest file.

Edit:

Look, these days fused location provider is being used and there do come some instances where you don't get the permission and location doesn't come up. Read this file which is a basic example for retrieving location -

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location/blob/master/BasicLocationSample/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/location/sample/basiclocationsample/MainActivity.java

Also, this is the guide for it -

https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html

Comment: The github example doesn't work. And if I understood it the right way, the google example just gives you the LAST known location, but not the actual.

Comment: Yeah, the google example gives the last known location, but if it's not available, you'll have to send a request for location update. The github example I gave you is part of a repo (you can look at it once you go there). The repo is the official one that came along with the guide. Look at the other files. There can be permission issues.

Comment: This command is not accepted by Android Studio: import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient;

Comment: compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.0' - add this in your app level gradle script inside the dependencies section

Comment: something like -

Comment: dependencies{ ................................................................................................    com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient;}